# QGIS QChainage layer not saving

Tags: qgis

ive created a point layer using the QChainage plugin and im able to change it it as i would a normal layer.. but the thing is that after i save and exit and re enter the qgis file the layer is gone .. is there a way to save it as an shp file so i can load it later on and use it with different files?

[image][image]

Answer (score 4):

The QChainage plugin delivers a memory layer. You can manually save it as a shape file with right click 'Save As' context menu in TOC.

An alternative to the QChainage plugin is the GRASS function v.to.points in Processing. There you can choose the resulting point file directly.

Note QChainage and v.to.points works slightly different regarding point interpolation at vertexes.

Comment: using "save as" on the qchainage layer gives me the option of saving it into many types of files just not .shp

Comment: @AbdullahAlaa please provide a screenshot of the available file type options

Comment: i uploaded the pictures, hope they'll give a better explanation

Comment: @AbdullahAlaa What is wrong with the *ESRI Shapefile* option in that drop-down?  Isn't that what you're after?

Comment: Maybe you should leave the edit mode of the qchainage layer. It is not required for saving to another file format.

Comment: @AbdullahAlaa, as Midavalo writes it is call ESRI Shapefile and not .shp or Shapefile in the save as dialog in QGIS TOC (table of content / layer control).

Comment: thanks.. i got to that eventually ... thank you for the answer

Comment: Then you should accept the answer for future record and delete the dublicate question at https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/237009/qgis-saving-memory-layers.